# How do I create a search engine or modify an existing one for searches only within a website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, search-engine

I am creating a website using Ruby on Rails, HTML (of course), CSS (of course), JavaScript, Sqlite 3, and Ajax while running an Apache server.

I want to have a search feature that only searches for content on the website: people, places, ideas, topics, etc.

How would I go about getting such a feature on my website and what search "programs" would you advise?

P.S. I already am aware of the Google search thingy.

Comment: If you're creating a site with Ruby on Rails, then you should already know how to use Ruby on Rails, and since it's server-side code, it's where you'd create a custom search function, no?

Comment: I am learning Rails right now.

Comment: Then you should learn about ruby gems and have a look there.

Answer (score 1):

This question feels like you haven't even bothered to investigate it by yourself.

I guess all your content is coming from your database? You have to connect your database with your searchengine and search for your data.

You should probably search for a [tutorial](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/php-pdo-sqlite3-example/) on SQLite Databases.